# Java SWT Changing text color when combobox setEnabled() is false

Tags: java, swt

When I use the setEnabled() on comboboxes,(and its set to false) I'm wondering how I can change the text color so it is black and not gray. The people I'm developing software for, and myself, find it too hard to read and I can't find a way to access the text color. It was easy fixing text components as I just had to use setEditable() instead which did not gray the text color but there is not a setEditable() method available to comboboxes in SWT.

To further clarify, I have tried to override the method, but it won't use my method, instead it uses the inherited method below...

```
public void setEnabled (boolean enabled) {
    checkWidget ();
    /*
    * Feature in Windows.  If the receiver has focus, disabling
    * the receiver causes no window to have focus.  The fix is
    * to assign focus to the first ancestor window that takes
    * focus.  If no window will take focus, set focus to the
    * desktop.
    */
    Control control = null;
    boolean fixFocus = false;
    if (!enabled) {
        if (display.focusEvent != SWT.FocusOut) {
            control = display.getFocusControl ();
            fixFocus = isFocusAncestor (control);
        }
    }
    enableWidget (enabled);
    if (fixFocus) fixFocus (control);
}
```

I can't find the text painting code in here, and now I'm becoming a little more confused as I am somewhat more familiar with Swing which has the UIManager
in which case it would look something like UIManager.put( "ComboBox.disabledText", Color.black); I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for SWT... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color of disabled component is one of those things which depends on system, so it's not possible to change the color.

You can use `CCombo` instead, which is much more usable and have exactly your requirements (disabled have black color of text and the color could be set by setForeground method). See [CCombo snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet39.java?view=co) for details..